# HTML Data Presentation Model

Tags: html, data-presentation

I'm building this site that is connected do databases. I obviously use HTML, PHP and SQL, and have three databases: Clients, Devices and Device Records.

When I open the site, I want a table to show all the clients and the number of devices they have (this is done). Then, when I click a given client, I want a table showing all the devices from that client, and then when I click a given device (they are all unique), I want to see their records.

So, my question is: what is the best way to do this? I know I can build a page for each thing, but this will be hard if I have hundreds of clients, each having hundreds of devices. Is there a better way?

Comment: Umm, use `$_GET`? It's kinda fundamental  to doing just about anything with PHP.

Comment: @Quentin, care to explain what you mean?

Comment: Probably not without writing an introductory PHP course.

Comment: Show us the page/code you wrote for "(this is done)".

Comment: My first question would be about your database design, why are these informations on different databases if they're linked ?

Comment: @LGSon, it is an HTML page presenting a table, that fetches information (using PHP) from a database.

Daniel, a client can have multiple devices, and a device has multiple records (records = automatic measurements of some parameters).

I forgot to add that this is a "live" thing, with information being automatically fed to the Records database.

Comment: Ahh, so this is easy.... :) On the first page, which you do have already, when you click on a client, you pass the client id to a second page, which collects all devices that belongs to that client and put them in a new table. On the second page, when you click on a device, you pass both the client id and the device id to a third page, which collects all device records and again create a third table. Done. (This can be done using either AJAX or normal page load)

Comment: Hi @LGSon, thanks for the help! So, those would be "generic" pages, right? Can you point me to a link where I can learn more about that? I'm not very proficient using AJAX.

Comment: Yepp, generic, and if you want to start with AJAX, this one show its basics, http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/, and for further reading just google for "ajax tutorial" and you saved your day with what to do :)